# Scrolling grid of Async Images with Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to create a Kivy layout that loads a grid of AsyncImage elements in a scrolling view.

I've tried using a couple different combinations of elements, but haven't been successful.

My closest attempt was putting a GridLayout inside of a ScrollView, then adding AsyncImages to the GridLayout, but there were huge gaps between the elements and I couldn't view more than one column at a time.

Any assistance with this would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I suggest using `size: self.minimum_size` for the `GridLayout` as well as the `col_default_width` and `row_default_height `properties. The `Images` will need the `allow_stretch` property set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of doing what you want,

It Loads all the images that are present into a path to gridlayout and then add GridLayout to ScrollView.

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from os import listdir, path
from os.path import isfile, join
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class RMassets(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RMassets,self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def doit(self):
        self.C_L = GridLayout(cols = 3, spacing = 0, size_hint = (None, None), size = (Window.size[0]/2, Window.size[1]),pos = (0,0))
        self.C_L.bind(minimum_height = self.C_L.setter('height'))

        mypath = "./Images/"
        #Getting All Images Names from path
        onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]

        #Adding All images to GridLayout
        for j in range(len(onlyfiles)):
            fname = mypath + onlyfiles[j]
            img = AsyncImage(source = fname, keep_ratio = True, allow_stretch =True)
            img.size_hint_y = None
            self.C_L.add_widget(img)

        #Adding GridLayout to ScrollView
        self.ids.SV1.add_widget(self.C_L)

        self.ids.ad.text = "Done"
        self.ids.ad.disabled = True

class myApp(App):
    pass

myApp().run()
```

Here is my kv file

my.kv

```
RMassets:

<RMassets>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        size_hint: None, None
        size: (root.size[0], root.size[1])
        ScrollView:
            id: SV1
            do_scroll_x: False
            do_scroll_y: True
                
        Button:
            id:ad
            text:"Add Images"
            on_press: root.doit()
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. However, all the images are still displaying very small. Is there a way to make it so that the images are scaled to take up the full width of the grid layout?

Comment: According to me you can Increase the Image Size by

1.Reducing column count

2.keep_ratio = False and allow_stretch = True(but it will make image appear bad if used with allow_stretch = True also this will show every image in same ratio(equal size) that will destroy image's default ratio hence destroy image quality if images are of different sizes)

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, but it ultimately did not result in what I was hoping for. I also tried to switch to a stack layout and then set the size_hint for each async image, but that didn't work either.

Comment: I fixed this by listening to @John Anderson's advice with setting `col_default_width ` and `col_default_width `

Comment: @CDD that's nice, now you can answer your question, and it will help all of us to understand.